# How can i redirect html page extension to php using htaccess

Tags: php, html, redirect

How can i redirect html page extensions to php using proper htaccess redirect as similar to this http://www.hd2wallpapers.com/butterfly_green-wallpapers.html gets redirected to http://www.hd2wallpapers.com/butterfly_green-wallpapers.php.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990240/redirect-all-html-extensions-to-php

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

if only this :

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://www.hd2wallpapers.com/butterfly_green-wallpapers.html http://www.hd2wallpapers.com/butterfly_green-wallpapers.php
```