# Having issues with Parsing PHP in .HTML Files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, parsing

I have an issue parsing PHP in `HTML` Files.

I am using an install of Vesta and the domain is running fine. The site in question has

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php4 .htm .html
# and 
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html
```

in the [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess), which before I moved server it was allowing php to run in html. I have also tried every single variant of this which I have found on stack overflow and none of them are working.

I can't figure out for the life of me why its not now working?

Has anybody got any ideas? 
Thank you 
Dan Williams

Comment: Maybe because you have `AllowOverride None` set in apache configuration, and your .htaccess is not being parsed at all?

Comment: Thanks for the reply DKasipovic, I will have a look in a bit. I think it might be though because it is finding the 404 page... Thanks

Comment: I also suggest another solution, just find a way to link to php files. Html files don't excecute php for a reason ;)

Comment: Yea, I think it's nasty too. But just got hosting for a site that isn't mine, and this is how has been coded :/

Comment: `AllowOverride All` is the current method set. Im a bit stumped by this one? @DKasipovic @Martijn

Answer (score 0):

Since your server *will not* allow you to use `PHP` in `HTML`, just rewrite all .html requests to php in [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Should solve the problem. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5990276/2119863)

**Why won't it parse PHP in HTML?**

The more types of files the server needs to push through the php interpreter, the more memory, processor and electricity it will consume. It's like with cars and trucks. Cars do not haul big trailors for a reason - trucks have much bigger engines and take the load but leave a bigger carbon footprint.

The second reason is the separation of functionalities. Seeing a html file, you should be 100% confident - across all and any servers - that this file will not `print_r($_SERVER);`. And when seeing a php file, you should be confident it performs some dynamic actions. And just like you shouldn't expect a nurse to build houses, neither should you expect HTML to parse PHP. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately this throws 404 errors saying that index.php does not exist. I would change all the pages to PHP if it were my site, but it's not - i'm just hosting it :(