# Calling class method in PHP through object not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to call class method as usual. The problem is that when `->` is entered to call method by object at following line

```
$Error = $obj->set($Name,$Fname,$Gender,$Email,$Password);
```

after -> same code prints on page.

I mean perhaps compiler consider `>` in `object->set()` as closing tag of PHP. My page is saved as html extension and all other HTML code work right, but method is not calling and text after `->` printing as it is on page.

Following is my code

```
<?php
include 'Validation.php';
$obj= new formvalidate;
if(isset($_POST['signup'])) 
{


    $Name=$_POST['name'];
    $Fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $Gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $Email=$_POST['email'];
    $Password=$_POST['password'];
    $Error = $obj->set($Name,$Fname,$Gender,$Email,$Password);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Most web server won't run php in files that don't have .php extension. So .html files are treated as plain html files. Content between < and > are treated as html tag.

Change your extension to .php so, web server will parse php code.

Comment: If you want to make your PHP code look like HTML, you can do this with your `.htaccess` - See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5990276/952608