# How to RewriteRule php to js extension with multiple parameters in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js?$ index.php?js=$1&key=$2
```

Original URL

```
/index.php?js=myscript&key=mykey
```

The Rewritten URL

```
/myscript.js?key=mykey
```

The PHP Source

```
$kunci = @$_GET['key'];

if (isset($kunci))
            {
            if ($kunci == "xxx")
                {
                echo $abc;
                }
              else
                {
                echo $def;
                }
            }
    else{
        echo $ghi;
    }
```

How to RewriteRule Original URL to Rewritten URL?

When I type I want `domain.com/myscript.js?key=123` get page and `domain.com/myscript.js` get page too like condition in PHP source above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect all .html extensions to .php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990240/redirect-all-html-extensions-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/coba/([^/]+)\.js$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php?js=%1&key=%2 [L]
```

Comment: when I type `domain.com/myscript.js?key=123` I got `404` and `domain.com/myscript.js` got `404` too

Comment: I get the same 404

Comment: Yes, I've cleaned up even I tried in different browsers. I always use private mode. you can check `tokojs[dot]com/app/coba/asli.js` and `tokojs[dot]com/app/coba/asli.js?key=123`

Comment: Well, I've checked it here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it is working please make sure no other rule is conflicting.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ index.php?js=%1&key=%2 [L]` This rule was not met.

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=cd253e9d-5fb1-5456-8609-814570c701b5

Comment: You have to use rewritten url my friend not original url try now http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=a55fa782-b53e-5343-9cf7-53ed2d8c7ab9

Comment: In the .htaccess file I just typed it. https://image.prntscr.com/image/654c493dd49042a4ab6206d1e9b3cc19.png

Comment: I just placed the .htaccess file in directory: /app/coba/.htaccess https://image.prntscr.com/image/4176fc6ecc41459cbbf14e3a01c202ae.png

Comment: Remove full url the rewrite_uri from the rule if you are using in app/coba/ directory