# How can I direct index.html to index.php?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How can ı do a index html direct to wp index.php (Latest version of Wordpress). I reviewed the canonical.php but no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple .htaccess rule as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990240/redirect-all-html-extensions-to-php).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Add this to the .htaccess file in the root of your website.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but ı use default wordpress htaccess. I tried, but the result  was unsuccessful

Comment: Exactly what i want to do a html file direct to wordress script :)